# Angularjs module error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I am new to angularJs, trying to make app which use camera and save images in firebase. I am following one tutorial and getting this error. I tried to fix it but it didn't work out. Pls help guys.

I posted my code on github. https://github.com/brunocoder/ImageApp

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

This is index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <title></title>

      <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angularfire.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

      <ion-pane>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
          <ion-nav-back-button>
          </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-pane>
    </body>
  </html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
var imageApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngRoute', 'firebase']);
var fb = new Firebase("myFirebaseAccountId");



imageApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
imageApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state("firebase",{
      url : "/firebase",
      templateUrl : "templates/firebase.html",
      controller : "FirebaseController",
      cache : false
    })
    .state("secure",{
      url : "/secure",
      templateUrl : "templates/secure.html",
      controller : "SecureController",
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/firebase");
});

imageApp.controller("FirebaseController", function($scope, $state, $firebaseAuth){
  var fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(fb);
  $scope.login = function(username, password){
    fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
      email : username,
      password : password
    }).then(function(authData){
      $state.go("secure");
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.error("Error : "+error);
    });
  }
  $scope.register = function(username, password){
    fbAuth.$createUser({email:username, password:password}).then(function(userData){
        return fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
          email:username,
          password: password
        });
    }).then(function(authData){
      $state.go("secure");
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error : " +error);
    });
  }
});

imageApp.controller("SecureController", function($scope, $ionicHistory, $firebaseArray, $cordovaCamera){
  $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
  $scope.images= [];
  var fbAuth = fb.getAuth();
  if fbAuth(){
    var userReference = fb.child("users/" + fbAuth.uid);
    var syncArray = $firebaseArray(userReference.child("images"));
    $scope.images = syncArray;
  }else {
    $state.go("firebase")
  }

  $scope.upload = function(){
    var option = {
      quality : 75,
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit : true,
      encodingType : Camera.encodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions : CameraPopoverOptions,
      targetWidth : 500,
      targetHeight : 500,
      saveToPhotoAlbum : false,
    }
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData){
      syncArray.$add({image:imageData}).then(function(){
        alert("The image was saved.");
      });
    }, function(error){
        console.error( "Error: " + error);
    });
  }
});
```

firebase.html

```
 <ion-view  title="Firebase">
   <ion-content>
     <div class="">
         <div class="list list-inset">
           <label class="item item-input">
            <input ng-model="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input ng-model="password" type="text" placeholder="password">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-left padding-right">
            <div class="button-bar">
                <a class="button" ng-click="login(username, passowrd)">Login</a>
                <a class="button" ng-click="register(username, passowrd)">Register </a>

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

secure.html

```
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-camera" ng-click="upload()">Camera</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < images.length">
          <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{images[$index].image}}" width = "100%" />
        </div>

        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
          <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{images[$index + 1].image}}" width = "100%" />
        </div>

        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
          <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{images[$index + 2].image}}" width = "100%" />
        </div>

        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 3 < images.length">
          <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{images[$index + 3].image}}" width = "100%" />
        </div>

      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15270:17
    at ensure (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15194:38)
    at module (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15268:14)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17674:22
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at createInjector (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17584:11)
    at doBootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14942:20)
    at bootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:12)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a code snippet here so folks don't have to debug your entire repository? Try reproducing the problem with a simplified version of your app.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with the code. Pls help

Comment: Try bringing all your scripts inside body tag after ion-pane tag.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem without ionic? most of your code deals with ionic, which is irrelevant if myApp can't be instantiated. Do you get any other errors that might prevent app.js to get loaded?

Comment: What you've posted seems just fine.  I suspect you have an issue where app.js is not parsed correctly, probably because of a syntax error.  Check your console for an error.

Comment: This is the error which is shown in console.

Comment: @brunocoder for one, it looks like `angular.min.js` is in the `js/` folder, but your script  tag doesn't list it under `js/` like the other scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the ionic bundle already specified which includes Angular by default. Remove your reference to angular, angular-route and few others and you should be good to go!